Summation of n-simplex numbers
Gauss proved that every positive integer is a sum of at most three triangular(2-simplex) numbers. I was thinking of an extension related to n-simplex.
Refer: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f9/Pascal_triangle_simplex_numbers.svg/800px-Pascal_triangle_simplex_numbers.svg.png
Let f(n) be a function that gives maximum number of terms(n-simplex numbers)
required for any positive number. The pattern seems like for even inputs f(2n) = 5n-2 and for odd inputs f(2n-1) = 5n-5.
f(2) = 3 (Triangular Numbers)
f(3) = 5
f(4) = 8
f(5) = 10
f(6) = 13
f(7) = 15
Can someone please guide me. Any lead would be helpful. Thanks in advance!

https://oeis.org/A356037 tabulates "Conjecturally, the smallest number $m$ such that every natural number is a sum of at most $m$ $n$-simplex numbers." The table doesn't go very far: just $1, 3, 5, 8, 10, 13, 15, 15, 19, 24$. If I'm reading the text there correctly, no one has proved any of these numbers to be correct, beyond the number $3$ for the triangular numbers. Some links to the literature are given there.
